# Hibernate Named Query: syntax error near ,

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I'm tryint to run a Postgres function as a named query in hibernate.

My function signature is:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_function(par1 integer[] DEFAULT '{}'::integer[],  par2 integer[] DEFAULT '{}'::integer[])
RETURNS TABLE(id integer, name character varying, qualified_name) AS
```

As you can see parameters are arrays of integer.

Here is my query mapping:

```
<sql-query name="myFn" callable="true">
        <return-scalar column="id" type="int" />
        <return-scalar column="name" type="string" />
        <return-scalar column="qualified_name" type="string" />
        { ? = call dummy_function(:par1, :par2)}  
</sql-query>
```

When I try to perform my query:

```
Query query = session.getNamedQuery("myFn");

query.setParameterList("par1", arrayList1.toArray());
query.setParameterList("par2", arrayList2.toArray());

query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyCustomBean.class));
result = (List<MyCustomBean>) query.list();
```

I get the following error: "syntax error near ," (complete stack trace is reported below).

Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
Laura

=====STACK TRACE ========

> WARN [main] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:144) - SQL Error: 0, SQLState:
>   42601 ERROR [main] (SqlExceptionHelper.java:146) - ERROR: syntax error
>   at or near ","   Posizione: 26 ERROR [main]
>   (NamedQueryTestCase.java:104) -
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet org.hibernate.HibernateException:
>   org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract
>   ResultSet     at
>   eu.test.dataLayer.TestDao.stackOverflowQuestion(TestDao.java:4412)    at
>   eu.test.test.NamedQueryTestCase.testGetHostsComponentsLevel(NamedQueryTestCase.java:98)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)    at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>     at
>   org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)  at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)     at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)   at
>   org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
>     at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)    at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
>   Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not
>   extract ResultSet     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:123)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:91)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2066)   at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1863)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1839)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:910)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:355)
>     at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2554)     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2540)  at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2370)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2365)    at
>   org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1909)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
>     at eu.test.dataLayer.TestDao.stackOverflowQuestion(TestDao.java:4407)
>     ... 25 more Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:
>   syntax error at or near ","   Posizione: 26   at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
>     at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)    at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:161)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:114)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:82)
>     ... 39 more

Comment: you should post the complete stack trace and not just the part you are considering to be relevant. And before moving to named query have you tried it as native SQL query that may help you to check the error

Comment: You don't need a "callable statement". `select from dummy_function()` will work just fine

Comment: Updated with complete stack trace and procedure return details. Of course I tried native SQL too (from Hibernate). The procedure works fine by command line.

Comment: Is there any one who has experienced a problem like this?

Comment: Update hibernate to the latest possible version. It is a bug in an old version, check the bug report [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-2776)